# DocuSign API: Assign a delivery method to a TemplateRole to send SMS to a signer

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I'm trying to make it so that specific signers to a document can be sent an envelope via SMS instead of email. I am using server templates to create the envelopes, but the examples don't seem to agree on whether to use a TemplateRole or use a Signer to create the envelope. So far I've been using TemplateRole, but it does not seem like there is a delivery method option (for only SMS).

In looking for answers I found a small reference to a bug "TT-3902" that was referenced [two years ago](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/sms-delivery-the-esignature-rest-api) and also on a post to the [Java SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client/issues/185), but at the same time another post from [a year ago](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/sms-delivery-update) says it is possible - but the link to the API Explorer shows only using a Signer object, not a TemplateRole object...

Questions: Can I use the TemplateRole this way but haven't found the right example? Is there a workaround? Has bug TT-3902 been fixed? Do I need to recode my entire Envelope creation process to be different just to use the Signer objects instead?

Current Code (using Python SDK):

```py
            signer = TemplateRole(
                role_name=signer_provided["role_name"],
                name=signer_provided["name"],
                email=signer_provided["email"],
                tabs=tabs,
            )
```

What I want to program for SMS delivery:

```py
            phone_number = RecipientPhoneNumber(country_code="1", number=signer_provided["phone_number"])
            signer = TemplateRole(
                delivery_method="SMS",
                role_name=signer_provided["role_name"],
                name=signer_provided["name"],
                phone_number=phone_number,
                tabs=tabs,
            )
```

I also tried:

```py
            phone_number = RecipientPhoneNumber(country_code="1", number=signer_provided.get("phone_number"))
            additional_notification = RecipientAdditionalNotification(secondary_delivery_method="SMS", phone_number=phone_number)
            signer = TemplateRole(
                additional_notification=additional_notification,
                role_name=signer_provided["role_name"],
                name=signer_provided["name"],
                email=signer_provided["email"],
                tabs=tabs,
            )
```

But this only sent an email (using my developer account) and not an SMS at all. I would like it to **only** send via SMS in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [Composite Templates](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/composite/) for this to work

Here is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "envelopeDefinition": {
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
      {
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "serverTemplates": [
          {
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "1b66677c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-655a7c3890d9"
          }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
          {
            "sequence": "1",
            "recipients": {
              "signers": [
                {
                  "name": "Signer Name",
                  "roleName": "signer",
                  "deliveryMethod": "SMS",
                  "recipientId": "1",
                  "phoneNumber": {
                    "countryCode": "",
                    "number": ""
                  },
                  "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [
                      {
                        "tabLabel": "signer_title",
                        "value": "Manager"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "envelopesCreateQP": {}
}
```

Comment: I wish there was a way without refactoring my envelope creation code, but seems like what you're saying is there isn't a way to use TemplateRole, and I have to use the Signer object to control delivery method (which is only accessible using Composite Templates). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just a side-note: by designing around the Composite Templates model, your codebase has the right structure to flex for different use cases without having to refactor the way you go about creating the envelope.  For example, to go from one document overlaid by one serverTemplate to two documents, each overlaid by a different template, is impossible using the templateRoles model, but almost trivial for composite templates.